# Was Trevor really insomniac for a year?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-machinist

I've just recently watched *The Machinist* and in the whole movie only once I heard that *Trevor Reznik* said he hasn't slept for a year. Was this really the case or he just imagined he hasn't slept in a year like everything else?

Answer (score 5):

I think he had awake for a year, but there's two possibilities depending on the intended realism:

He had been awake for a year (artistic licence):
Trevor would (roughly) know how long it'd been (perhaps estimating or rounding).
Severe sleep deprivation can lead to many kinds of physical and mental problems including: paranoia, weight loss, hallucinations and moodiness.
The rest of the film (Trevor's physical condition, no other duration suggested) would support this.

He imagined it (more realistic):
He'd been awake for a long time but nowhere near a year, perhaps with unnoticed [microsleeps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsleep).
Records for healthy individuals staying awake without stimulants is around [11 days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randy_Gardner_%28record_holder%29), however patients with a sleeping disorder may stay awake far longer, the longest on record is a man with [FFI (a brain disorder)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatal_familial_insomnia) at 6 months (still far shorter than Trevor).